# Kernel closed implies continuous operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

Is closed kernel sufficient for linear operators to be continuous? Counterexample? Thx, Alex

Comment: No, this is false. Indeed, an injective linear operator can be discontinuous. Try taking a Hamel basis for your space and defining your operator on this basis in such a way that it's unbounded.

Comment: However, what you say is true for linear *functionals*. Perhaps you could explain what you have tried and what the context for the question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No it is not sufficient!**

Consider for example the linear operator:
$T:l^\infty\to l^\infty: T(\sum\alpha_n e_n+\sum\beta_b b):=\sum\alpha_n n e_n$ with hamel basis $\mathcal{B}=\{e_n\}_{n=0}^\infty\cup\{b\}_{b\in B}$
This operator has closed kernel but is not continuous.